# React Render Map last element doesnt update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Last FileComponent in map doesnt reflect state changes, it event doesnt call shouldComponentUpdate. After changing other FileComponents (but last) all of them except last one reflect changes and each calls shouldComponentUpdate.

In React component in render method i use this:

```
{this.props.files.map((file,index)=>{
    return (
        <FileComponent type="upload" key={index} index={index} />
    )
})}
```

In FileComponent i have button with onClick function:

```
this.props.dispatch({type: "EDIT_FILE", payload: this.props.index});
    // SOME STRANGE BEHAVIOUR
    // if(this.props.index+1 == this.props.files.length){
    //     this.forceUpdate();
    // }
```

My reducer contains:

```
function getInitialState(){
   return {
    files:  [
        {name: 'asd.doc', in_edit: false,
            file: {type:'image/png', size:123123, lastModifiedDate:new Date()}
        },
        {name: '22.doc', in_edit: false,
            file: {type:'image/png', size:123123, lastModifiedDate:new Date()}
        },
        {name: 'as33d.doc', in_edit: false,
            file: {type:'image/png', size:123123, lastModifiedDate:new Date()}
        },
        {name: '44.doc', in_edit: false,
        file: {type:'image/png', size:123123, lastModifiedDate:new Date()}
        },
    ]
}
}

export default function (state = getInitialState(), action) {
switch (action.type) {

 case "EDIT_FILE":
        state.files[action.payload]['in_edit'] = !state.files[action.payload]['in_edit'];
        return Object.assign({}, state);
default:
        return state
}
}
```

Package.json:

```
"react": "^15.3.2",
"react-dom": "^15.3.2",
"react-dropzone": "^3.7.3",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
```

Is it enought to understand my problem?

Comment: Your reducer mutates the state then you change only the reference to the state itself, but NOT the reference to your file. So redux doesn't know you changed a file.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't use the index as key in map but rather a unique id of the data (see: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.1jenrcz8e )

Comment: @mbernardeau thanks, im preparing to upload files to server, and on this step i dont have unique ids, and filenames are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change reducer code to operate with reference to files, not to whole state:

```
case "EDIT_FILE":
        let files = state.files.slice(0);
        files[action.payload]['in_edit'] = !files[action.payload]['in_edit'];

        return Object.assign({}, state, {files:files});
```